# Is there a way to restart tomcat6 on linux with verbose messaging?

Tags: tomcat6

Sometimes it takes over 2 minutes to start and I would like to see any messages during the startup.

yours,

Rob

Answer (score 1):

The easy way:

```
tail -f /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out
```

Or what\wherever the log is.  You should see any messages that go to the log up on your terminal.